# Function in map detect only one argument

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to compute the distance between all combinations of elements from two sets.

`descriptor_1` (resp. `descriptor_2`) is a list of 2D arrays of length N1 (resp. N2) (one 2D array per element).

To compute all combinations between these two sets, I use:

```
combi = list(itertools.product(descriptor_1, descriptor_2))
```

which yields a list of 2-uples of length `N1*N2`.

And to compute the distances:

```
dist = map(chi2_dist, combi)
```

where:

```
def chi2_dist(a, b):
    a = a.flatten()
    b = b.flatten()

    dist = (1/2) * np.sum( (a-b)**2 / (a+b+EPS))

    return dist
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: chi2_dist() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

But, as my tuples contain 2 elements, I do not understand the error.

Comment: can you post the output of the list combi

Comment: You are expecting `map` automatically unpack your tuples, but if it is really implemented as you expect, how about the users who truly want to pass a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fucntion should be

```
def chi2_dist(ab):
    a = ab[0]
    b = ab[1]
    a = a.flatten()
    b = b.flatten()
```

BTW, much more efficient to just

```
map(chi2_dist, itertools.product(descriptor_1, descriptor_2))
```

no need of an intermediate list